# Clicking "show comment" while editing a comment cancels the edit to the comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, edits

While editing a comment, if a new comment is posted by someone else, it's magically detected and a button appears asking if you want to load the new comment. Clicking this button whilst in the middle of the comment edit cancels the edit without warning (i.e. the textbox goes away and there's no way to recover the edited text).

Is this a bug?

Comment: This has been since fixed....

Comment: ...and is broken again, just noticed today :-( At least, it's broken when editing a comment, not sure about new comments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will behave as expected from the next build on.

Loading the rest of the comments technically replaces *all* comments and doesn't just add new ones, and this includes overwriting the edit box. We now remember what comment(s) you were in the midst of editing (and what you had changed so far), and update the UI accordingly after loading the comments. Thus to you it looks like the edit box never disappeared.